# Group by multiple colums request with result on a single line - Android SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to do some kind of `SELECT` ... `COUNT()` ... `GROUP BY` 2 columns (Month and Type) request on an SQLite database on Android. I could to the following request :

```
select Month, Type, Count()
from MyTable
group by Month, Type
```

My problem is that I'd like to display the result in a Android Listview using a cursor with :

- **one single line for each month**
- COUNTs of the (fixed and known number of) types.

Maybe something like :

```
select Month, Count(Type = A), Count(Type = B), Count(Type = C)
from MyTable
group by Month
```

**Database**

```
Month   |   Type
-------- ---------
Feb 15  |   A
Feb 15  |   B
Dec 15  |   A
Dec 15  |   A
Dec 15  |   B
Dec 15  |   C
```

**Expected result**

```
Month   |  'COUNT(A)'  |   'COUNT(B)'  |   'COUNT(C)'
-------- -------------- --------------- -------------
Feb 15  |   1          |   1          |   0
Dec 15  |   2          |   1          |   1
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
 month, 
 sum(case when "Type" = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as "count(a)",
 sum(case when "Type" = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as "count(b)",
 sum(case when "Type" = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as "count(c)"
from 
 mytable 
group by 
 month
```